# Alert visitor that the website may load slowly

Tags: html, performance, loading, alert, pagespeed

Is there a way to alert a visitor that the website may load slowly because of their slow connetion?
i.e.
Heads up!
The page seems to be loading slowly becasue of your connection. Please allow extra time for the website to load.

Comment: What about `alert("Heads up!
The page seems to be loading slowly becasue of your connection. Please allow extra time for the website to load");` ?

Comment: But if they don't have a slow conection I don't want the message popping up

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the user to *know* they have a slow connection already?

Comment: Depends on what you call a "slow connection" :)

Comment: if the page takes more than 20-30 seconds to load

Comment: If the page takes more than 20 seconds to load, I close it and go somewhere else. No need to show popup notifications.

Comment: @Peter likely they are already used to pages taking a while to load.  Or why not simply implement a loading icon or something that is displayed while the page content is being loaded?  That is a more typical UI/UX pattern for this kind of thing.

Comment: If I use a loading code, I can't find one that will change a message after x ammount of secods while loading

Comment: Is there any reason why your page would load slowly? Loading in a large amount of images for example.

Comment: no the rating for the website on pingdom is 98%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may download a known payload using ajax. Note down the request begin time and end time. If that is beyond some threshold you may alert the user about slow connection. For example, you download a 100 kb payload. You know under normal situations it takes 2 seconds. You may alert the user about slow network if it goes beyond acceptable threshold of say, 5 seconds. The payload you download need not be a waste request - you may use any ajax request for detecting the slow connections. This will work with one big assumption - your server is always responding quickly under heavy loads too - indicating only source of slow response is because of user's network conditions.

Comment: What payload do you suggest?

Comment: It may be anything - including some ajax request you do for downloading some data like, say, a country list or some other data. Only thing is - this should not be a highly dynamic data varying a lot on server side processing and download size. Then the request processing and download time will have more variables skewing the results. In the absence of any such real data, you may just keep a test json/test file on server side only for timing purposes. Yes, that will waste some bandwidth and processing cycles. But that is the best you can do in the absence of anything else.